# Scipy.stats binned_statistic_dd for 3D closest-to-centroid per bin

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

**Action**
Select closest to centroid for each bin in binned 3D point set.

**Attempts**
Using `binned_statistic_dd` from `scipy.stats` I tried to take the binned mean of this 3D pointset. However, it will only compute the mean for one of the dimensions at a time.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic_dd

points = np.array([range(2000), range(2000), range(2000)]).T
# points[:,1] is y
y_means, bin_edges, bin_indices = binned_statistic_dd(points, points[:, 1], statistic=np.mean, bins=np.cbrt(1000))
y_means.shape # (10,10,10)
```

Next would be to compute distance for each mean to all of the original points and take the closest. Resulting in the following full implementation:

```
def grid_sample(df):
    x_mean, edges, binnumber = binned_statistic_dd(df[['x', 'y', 'z']].values, df.x.values, bins=np.cbrt(1000), statistic=np.mean)
    y_mean, edges, binnumber = binned_statistic_dd(df[['x', 'y', 'z']].values, df.y.values, bins=np.cbrt(1000), statistic=np.mean)
    z_mean, edges, binnumber = binned_statistic_dd(df[['x', 'y', 'z']].values, df.z.values, bins=np.cbrt(1000), statistic=np.mean)
    xyz_mean = pd.DataFrame({'x_mean':x_mean.flatten(), 'y_mean':y_mean.flatten(), 'z_mean':z_mean.flatten()}).dropna()

    def find_nearest(point, df=df):
        idx = (np.sum(np.abs(df[['x', 'y', 'z']].values-point.values)**2, axis=1)**.5).argmin()
        return df.iloc[idx]

    df = xyz_mean.apply(find_nearest, axis=1)
    return df
```

**Question**
Two questions:

1. How can I avoid computing the binned statistic for each dimension?
2. Is there a smarter `closest-to-centroid` function? I could not find anything suitable in `scipy.stats`